# Change NSImage Origin

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsimage

Is it possible to change the origin of an NSImage? If so how would I go about doing this. I have coordinates in regular cartesian system some of them with negative values and I am trying to draw them at the corresponding point in the NSImage but since the origin is at (0,0) there are some missing.

EDIT:Say I have an drawing aspect that needs to be done to an image at the point (-10,-10), currently this doesn't show up. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing an NSImage with it's container. An NSImage has no bounds or frame, and thus no origin. It does have a *size*  which may represent the pixel dimensions of its birtmap representation ( if it has one) or otherwise could represent it's bounding box ( if it is a vector image). Drawing in an image at a pixel location of (-10,-10) doesn't really make sense.

An NSImage is displayed in a container ( typically an NSImageView), and  the container's bounds.origin will dictate the placement of the image relative to the imageView, but you can't modify pixels beyond the edge of the bitmap plane.

In any case you probably want to be using a subclassed NSView in which you would override the drawRect method for your custom drawing. NSView *does* have a bounds.origin but this is not relevant to your in-drawing coordinates, but rather to the position of the drawn content as a whole to the view's bounding box. The coordinate system that you will be drawing into will be referenced to your *graphics context* which will (usually) pin the origin (0,0) to the bottom left corner (OSX) or top left corner (iOS). If you are trying to represent negative points on a Cartesian plane, you will need to apply a translation transform to map your points into this positive coordinate space.

I'm trying to explain in a few words, badly, something which Apple explains in great detail in their [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Evidently through my multiple readings of that guide I missed this. Your explanation helped clear up my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If it's like in iOS (you may have to adapt a little the code) and if my memory is still good, you have to do this, since `origin` is *readOnly*:
`CGRect myFrame = yourImage.frame;`
`myFrame.origin.x=newX;` 
`myFrame.origin.y=newY;`

`yourImage.frame = myFrame;`

Comment: It is almost the same as iOS but your memory is a little rusty. Neither NSImage or it's iOS counterpart UIImage have a frame property. They have a _size_, but no _origin_ (see my answer below)...